# How to Convert Uint8List to File with Web

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am having trouble on converting Uint8List image to File on flutter web since dart:io is not supported on the web, i need it to be file in order to upload it to FirebaseStorage,

I have tried a few packages like path_provider and Unversal_io. However, it seems that these packges do not support Web.
my purpose is to upload images to firebase storage by files, since uploading by bytes takes a lot of space in the storage.
is there any actual way to achieve my case?

Comment: the matter is that the image uploaded with bytes, its size appears to be larger in the storage than uploaded with file. However, the main point is that i can't convert raw-data to file in Web flutter app.